# What is the right word order?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it correct to say:

The party is at my house in the garden.
OR
The party is in the garden at my house.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Either is correct, it would depend on the context to know which one is more appropriate to use. Welcome to the site, Please take the tour: https://english.stackexchange.com/tour and take a look through the help centre to familiarise yourself with our ways: https://english.stackexchange.com/help  You might consider joining our sister site for English language learners here:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say. Is "my house" in "the garden" (first sentence) or is "the garden" at "my house" (second sentence). Both as valid sentences, ignoring the truth value of their meaning.

There is a third sentence that has the same word order as the first sentence, but has a meaning close to that of the second:

> The party is at my house, in the garden.

Here "in the garden" clarifies the first part of the sentence. In this case you can infer that being in the garden makes it also be at the house. So, this sentence implies that the garden is at the house, just like your second sentence would claim.

Comment: +1 Good observation about the different reference points.